# What is the difference between setting a value to a formGroup object via assignment and by using patchValue()?

Tags: angular8, angular-reactive-forms

If i use the Reactive Form's patchValue() function to assign values to my object, how different will it be if i assign it a value through the assigment operator?

I have already run the code and the values are being set to the "customer" object i.e: both work similarly. Can some please tell if there are any subtle underlying differences that I am missing or if there are any apparent differences that I am not getting?

---

**customer class : customer.ts**

```
export class Customer {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    age: number;
    active: boolean;
    myproduct: {
        p_id : number;
    }
}
```

---

**customer object :  create-customer-component.ts**

```
customer = this.fb.group({
    id: null,
    name : ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]],
    age : ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(18),Validators.max(100)]], 
    active: false,
    myproduct:this.fb.group(
      { p_id : null
      })
  })
```

---

**the two aforementioned options**

```
this.customer.value.myproduct.p_id = 1;
this.customer.patchValue({p_id : 2}) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Set value but it won't be showing in input box or you can use
this.customer.controls['p_id '].setValue('Any Id');

Comment: I am asking how the two ways are different.